# Como hago para que me envie solo el ultimo archivo que genero?

Tags: php, mysql, android

Tengo el siguiente caso: El siguiente codigo que presento es para generar Codigos QR partiendo de una consulta de la base de datos, todo perfecto, el codigo lo genera, lo envia al correo ingresado ajuntado como PNG y todo perfecto, pero tiene un detalle, que me envia por cada email que ingrese 15 correos porque genero 15 codigos QR y claro porque esta enviando lo que esta adjuntando, quiero saber, como hago para que solo envie el ultimo producto que se inserto en la tabla y que si los otros PNG ya existen no los vuelva a enviar, sino el ultimo que se genero, AYUDA POR FAVOR. El correo claro adjunta individualmente el PNG, pero por ejemplo si te envio uno ahorita te llegan 15 correos individualmente con los codigos de las caracteristicas de los productos, si te lo envio una segunda vez te vuelve a enviar los otros 15 y asi, entonces eso es como que demasiado exagerado.

Adjunto el codigo:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
    //*Conexion a base de datos *//

    $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "contrumeca"); 

    $codigosqr = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT codproducto, nombre_producto, margen_utilidad, unidad_manejo, descripcion, proveedor, precio, existencia, tipo_producto, imagen FROM producto ORDER BY codproducto ASC");

    $response = array();   
    $correo = $_POST['correo'];

    //*Generando el codigo QR *//
    require 'phpqrcode/qrlib.php';

    $directorio = '';

    //*Si no existe la carpeta *//

    $filename = $directorio.'test.png';   


    //*El bucle y el envio del correo *//

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($codigosqr))
   {    

    $filename = $directorio. "".$row['codproducto'].'.png';

    $archivo = $filename;      

    $contenido = "Identificador: {$row['codproducto']}, {$row['nombre_producto']}, Por:{$row['unidad_manejo']}, {$row['descripcion']}, {$row['precio']}, {$row['tipo_producto']}";

    QRCode::png($contenido, $filename);

    echo '<img src ="'.$directorio.basename($filename).'"/><hr/>';

    echo $archivo;    

    $response = array();   
    if(!empty($_POST['correo']))
    {  

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios_noadministradores WHERE correo = '$correo'";

    $query = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        if($count == 1) 
        {

           require 'PHPMailer/vendor/autoload.php';

           $mail = new PHPMailer();     

           $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;   
           $mail->isSMTP();   
           $mail->CharSet="UTF-8";  
           $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
           $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
           $mail->Username = 'contrumeca.ca@gmail.com';
           $mail->Password = '25408448g';
           $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
           $mail->Port = 587;                                         

           $mail->setFrom('contrumeca.ca@gmail.com', 'Construcciones Metalurgicas C.A');
           $mail->addAddress($_POST["correo"]);             
           $mail->addAttachment($archivo);            

           $mail->isHTML(true);                                 
           $mail->Subject = 'Codigo QR generado';
           $mail->Body    = "<p>Estimado/a, {$row['nombre']}
           <br>
           <p>Reciba un cordial saludo desde Construcciones Metalurgicas. A traves de la presente es para informarle que el Codigo QR ha sido generado de manera exitosa desde la aplicación oficial de Contrumeca C.A, el cual se le ha sido adjuntado en formato PNG</p>

           <p>Le invitamos a escanear el codigo a traves del Lector Oficial de la aplicación oficial, para asi corroborar que los datos del mismo coincidan con lo que se registro</p>

           <p>Sin nada mas a que hacer referencia</p>
           <br>
           <p>Atentamente.</p>

           <p>Ing. Giusseppe Micco</p>

           <p>Analista de Ventas Contrumeca C.A</p>
           <br>
           <br>
           <br>
           <br>
           <p>Este mensaje solo debio ser recibido por el destinatario arriba indicado y puede contener informacion privilegiada o confidencial. Si usted lo ha recibido por error, le agradecemos notificarlo de inmediato a: contrumeca.ca@gmail.com . Gracias</p>";       


           if(!$mail->send()) {

              $response["success"] = false;
               $response["message"] = "Correo no enviado";
           } else {
               $response["success"] = true;
               $response["message"] = "success";
           }




     } 
     echo json_encode($response);    

       }
    }   


    }

  ?>
```

Gracias..

Comment: Si escribes la consulta así: **`SELECT codproducto, nombre_producto, margen_utilidad, unidad_manejo, descripcion, proveedor, precio, existencia, tipo_producto, imagen FROM producto ORDER BY codproducto DESC LIMIT 1`** te va a traer solamente el último que se generó. El problema es que los estás trayendo todos sin necesidad.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, funciono de maravilla!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

En MySQL puedes usar [`LIMIT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/limit-optimization.html) para indicar la cantidad de filas que quieres en el resultado.

Si quieres únicamente el último registro, puedes escribir la consulta así:

```
SELECT 
    codproducto, 
    nombre_producto, 
    margen_utilidad, 
    unidad_manejo, 
    descripcion, 
    proveedor, 
    precio, 
    existencia, 
    tipo_producto, 
    imagen 
FROM producto 
ORDER BY codproducto DESC LIMIT 1
```

El problema es que los estás trayendo todos sin necesidad.